# link rollover to change the background image

Tags: hyperlink, hover, background-image, rollover

is there a way to alter a background when you rollover a link? im making a degree show website and want a large sample image to appear in the background when you rollover the link of persons name. i have an image appearing, however its covering all the text and in a fixed position over the link. is there a way to do this so it just alters the background image and stays behind all the other text on the page?

heres what im working with

```
#hover_img img
{
display:none;
}

#hover_img:hover img
{
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
padding-top:0px;

}
```

html

```
  <div id="hover_img">LINK<img src="image" alt="" /></a></div>
```

thanks!

** fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5yhsL/ **

Comment: There's an error in your html. You start off with <div> and end with </a>.

Comment: there's a div aswell, sorry forgot to add that! just edited

Comment: Ok, but now there's the beginning of the a-tag missing: <a href="#">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add z-index: -1 to the image on hover:

```
#hover_img:hover img
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: nope. its going behind the usual background image.. there's a random background image going on besides the rollover!

Comment: and its appearing from where the text is placed, i want it appear on the whole page - top, left, 0px

Comment: @aaron_m12345 Is there a way you could post the html and css of the background image, perhaps in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: goodshout, its because im using this other fancy random image script i found, probably over complicates things. here we go http://jsfiddle.net/5yhsL/ thanks!

Comment: @aaron_m12345 There are a few errors in the fiddle which I have cleaned up: http://jsfiddle.net/5yhsL/4/. Now an image is displayed filling the whole background and covering the text. Is this the effect you want, except that the text is visible?

Comment: yeah i want it behind the text if possible, like the background

Comment: the second part of the javascript is meant to be in the body, dont know if that matters or not. thanks for your help, really appreciated

Comment: Are you using jquery or another javascript library?

Comment: It would make things easier since you write less code and the code that you write is supported by all browsers. I've updated the fiddle again. The image and link are set and in the background: http://jsfiddle.net/5yhsL/5/. What's supposed to happen when the mouse hovers over a link? Is one of the four images randomly displayed or the image in the link where the name is?

Comment: yeah the image link is meant to appear in the background when hovered over. is this doable without jquery?

Comment: looks perfect! though i cant seem to get it working on my own html page. any chance i could email the file so you could have a look? so annoying I dont know why it isnt working properly. maybe the jquerys in the wrong place? thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by putting the text inside another element adjacent to your image element. Absolutely positioned elements will take dominance over their neighbors, and one way you can get around that is by assigning a value to the position property for subsequent elements.

Here is a jsfiddle I've whipped up:

http://jsfiddle.net/93mpW/3/

Comment: thanks man put its not working with my other code at all. and then it still covers all the other text. thanks for your help though!